# Which analyzer is used while using fuzzy operator with query_string clause?

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

Suppose I have a query clause like,

```
{
    "query":
    {
  "query_string": {
    "query": "ads spark~",
    "fields": [
      "flowName",
      "projectName"
    ],
    "default_operator": "and"
  }
}
}
```

For this the explain output is:

```
"explanation": "+(projectName:ads | flowName:ads) +(projectName:spark~1 | flowName:spark~1)"
```

Whereas if I remove the fuzzy operator from query. Updated query clause below,

```
{
    "query":
    {
  "query_string": {
    "query": "ads spark",
    "fields": [
      "flowName",
      "projectName"
    ],
    "default_operator": "and"
  }
}
}
```

I get a different explain output,

```
"explanation": "(projectName:ads spark | flowName:ads spark)"
```

Any idea why the tokens generated as different in both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use fuzzy queries the way the query is parsed and constructed in Lucene differs from the normal behavior.
The one you see with the explanation is the Lucene query built from the query text.
When using fuzziness most of the text analysis is not done, only the filters that work on a per-character basis are allowed, as you can read in the documentation  [[1]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-fuzziness)[[2]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html).

In this first case, since you are using fuzziness, the query text is split by whitespaces. Then, for each term a mandatory clause is built (the AND operator states that each term MUST appear in the document). You can call this a "term centric" query. Then each term is searched across the multiple fields in input with a disjunction (|) clause.
You therefore see "ads MUST be in projectName OR flowName, AND spark (with variations within the [Levenshtein_distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance)) MUST be in projectName OR flowName".

In the second case, no fuzziness is used. Here the query is passed to each field and then the terms will follow the corresponding field text analysis (if any). You may call this a "field centric" query. Therefore you see "ads spark MUST be in projectName OR flowName" to have a document match.
You are effectively moving from an "I want all the terms to appear in the document" (it could be in different fields) to "I want all terms to appear in a single field".

If you want an in-depth analysis you can read this blog post https://sease.io/2021/05/apache-solr-sow-parameter-split-on-whitespace-and-multi-field-full-text-search.html. This is relative to Solr but Elasticsearch applies the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I want to have a term-centric approach here. 
The point you mentioned that since fuzziness is used the query text is split by whitespaces. Is it due to some default analyzer that is used for such cases?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, this is by default for those cases. It is something that can be seen looking at the project code/implementation of Lucene and Elasticsearch.

Comment: Interesting. Do you happen to have some reference to the code? It would be good to go over it. Plus it would also help me to have a starting point for future if I come across such issues.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not a reference right now..